# How To Make Multi Array in Unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How to convert the variable below to become Multi Array Variable ?

The code example :

```
public GameObject Mayonnaise;
    Text Qty;
    Text Price;
    Text Have;

    public GameObject Cheese;
    Text Qty;
    Text Price;
    Text Have;

    public GameObject Flour;
    Text Qty;
    Text Price;
    Text Have;

    public GameObject Sugar;
    Text Qty;
    Text Price;
    Text Have;
```

I want that gameobject Mayonnaise contain Qty, Price, Have;

So it will look like : Mayonnaise["qty","Price","Have"]

So I no need to create too many variable name with the same one.

How is it in Unity C# ?

Thanks

Comment: You can make an array of `GameObject`s like this. `public GameObjec[] sampleObjets` but you if i underesntad your question correclty you try to make array of gameobjects of `Text`s. You can also check `Dictionary` here is more info: [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary).

Comment: Could you make the example convert the code above ?

Comment: First i need to know why you want construction like this. Why did you create e.g `public GameObject Mayonnaise` and than `Text Qty` ,`Text Price`? Maybe you should consider to create class. E.g `public class Product { public Text Qty; public Text Price; public Text Have; }` and than create objects e.g: `public Product Mayonnaise = new Product(); Mayonnaise.Qty = //your text component` etc. [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want that gameobject Mayonnaise contain Qty, Price, Have;

A game Object cannot contain those. It looks like you are looking for a way to hold those those variables and using scripts to do this is appropriate.

> So I no need to create too many variable name with the same one

All you need is a script that holds each food type. You can then create arrays of each food type. This is what this question sounds to me and hopefully, I read this correctly.

If you look very close in your question, you will see that `Qty`,`Price`, and `Have` variables appeared in all scripts. This is where `inheritance` should be used.

`Food` class:

```
public class Food
{
    protected Text Qty;
    protected Text Price;
    protected Text Have;

    public void setQty(Text Qty)
    {
        this.Qty = Qty;
    }

    public void setPrice(Text Price)
    {
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    public void setHave(Text Have)
    {
        this.Have = Have;
    }

    public Text getQty()
    {
        return this.Qty;
    }

    public Text getPrice()
    {
        return this.Price;
    }

    public Text getHave()
    {
        return this.Have;
    }
}
```

You can then Create your `Mayonnaise`,`Cheese`,`Flour` and `Sugar` classes and inherit from `Food` on all of them.

```
public class Mayonnaise : Food
{

}

public class Cheese : Food
{

}

public class Flour : Food
{

}

public class Sugar : Food
{

}
```

Now, to answer your question about creating multiple arrays of them, below is like what you are looking for.

```
const int Size = 4;

Mayonnaise[] mayonnaise;
Cheese[] cheese;
Flour[] flour;
Sugar[] sugar;

void Start()
{
    mayonnaise = new Mayonnaise[Size];
    cheese = new Cheese[Size];
    flour = new Flour[Size];
    sugar = new Sugar[Size];

    //Create instance of of them
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        mayonnaise[i] = new Mayonnaise();
        cheese[i] = new Cheese();
        flour[i] = new Flour();
        sugar[i] = new Sugar();
    }

    mayonnaise[0].setHave(SomeTextComponent);
    mayonnaise[0].getHave().text = "Some Text";
    string text = mayonnaise[0].getHave().text;
}
```